# Language Analyzer doesnt work find singular results

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I have a bunch of categories with translations in my category field. I have defined language analyzers for the fields in my index so I can search for them. But it doesnt find the singular version of my words. `wasmachine` in `titles.title-nl` is singular of `wasmachines` but not found. What am I missing?

**Demo document**

```
    "_source" : {
      "google_id" : 2706,
      "titles" : [
        {
          "title-en" : "laundry appliances",
          "title-de" : "waschen & trocknen",
          "title-fr" : "appareils de blanchisserie",
          "title-nl" : "wasmachines"
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Way I mapped them**

```
PUT categories/_mapping/category
{
"dynamic": false,
"properties": {
"titles.title-nl": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "dutch"
},
"titles.title-en": {
    "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "english"
    },
    "titles.title-de": {
    "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "german"
    },
    "titles.title-fr": {
    "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "french"
    }
  }
}
```

**The way I search for them**

```
GET categories/_search
{
  "size": 4, 
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "wasmachines",
      "fields": ["titles.title-de","titles.title-en", "titles.title-fr", "titles.title-nl"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the default dutch analyzer doesn't know how to stem the word `wasmachines`, you will need to recreate your index with a custom analyzer using a `stemmer_override`.

Looking in the [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#dutch-analyzer) you can do the following to recreate the `dutch` analyzer and tell that `wasmachines` should be stemmed to `wasmachine`, just put `wasmachine => wasmachines` inside the rules for the `stemmer_override`

```
PUT categories/
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "dutch_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_dutch_" 
        },
        "dutch_keywords": {
          "type":       "keyword_marker",
          "keywords":   ["voorbeeld"] 
        },
        "dutch_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "dutch"
        },
        "dutch_override": {
          "type":       "stemmer_override",
          "rules": [
            "fiets=>fiets",
            "bromfiets=>bromfiets",
            "wasmachine=>wasmachines",
            "ei=>eier",
            "kind=>kinder"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_dutch": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "dutch_stop",
            "dutch_keywords",
            "dutch_override",
            "dutch_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will also need to use that new analyzer in your mapping:

```
PUT categories/_mapping/category
{
    "dynamic": false,
    "properties": {
        "titles.title-nl": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "rebuilt_dutch"
        },
        "titles.title-en": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "titles.title-de": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "german"
        },
        "titles.title-fr": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "french"
        }
    } 
}
```

After that you will be able to search for `wasmachine` and get the documents that have `wasmachines`.

Comment: Hey there Leandro! So it actually does stem, just doesn't understand that specific word?

Comment: Yeah, the way elasticsearch deals with singular, plural and verbal tenses is by stemming the words, but for some reason it does not know how to stem `wasmachines`.

Comment: @leandrojmp I did the same but for spanish. What I don't get is the mapping part.  And in the GET query you must specify the analyzer? Thanks